# Unable to load database when deployed the web application on IIS

Tags: sql-server, iis-7

I have a web application developed in .net and deployed on IIS and easily accessed from other systems on the LAN.

All working fine in local system but when deployed into IIS data not coming from database and only UI is getting loaded.

I post a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3Cy2.png) for your information.

Comment: How you use / test the web application on local system ? Under IIS Express ? Add more details

Comment: In my local system,i installed iis 7, Problem is that whenever i running my local application, application works fine, but when i deployed the application on iis at that time data is not coming from database.

Comment: Again: add more details: "local IIS [..] deployed the application on IIS" what mean ? Two distinct IIS ? Two Machine ? App Pool Identity ? 32/64 bit ? Folder permissions ? Authentication anonymous / windows ? You have SQL Server ? Users ? You MUST add more details and describe the entire scenario.